# C++ NOW: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions (Freebsd, GCC, Gmake )

Tags: c++

I need some help from an error generated by the compiler.

I hope you can help me.

This is the error message:

```
FILE.cpp: In function 'int Gamble(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&)':
FILE.cpp::6 :warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
FILE.cpp:10: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

And here is the code :

```
typedef std::vector <std::string> TTokenVector;

int Gamble(std::vector<float>& vec_probs)
{
    float range = 0.f;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_probs.size(); i++)    //Line  6
}
    float fProb = fnumber(0.f, range);
    float sum = 0.f;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < vec_probs.size(); idx++)   //LINE  10
{
        sum += vec_probs[idx];
        if (sum >= fProb)
            return idx;
}
    return -1;
}
```

The default compilator is freebsd ( GCC )

Comment: There are *loads* of duplicates here; please use the search facility before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the culprit

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec_probs.size(); i++)
```

Try

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec_probs.size(); i++)
```

The `int` type is signed, the `size_t` type (returned from `.size()`) is unsigned.

The same warning will occur in your next `for` loop

```
(int idx = 0; idx < vec_probs.size(); idx++)
```